# Cakephp routing is not working properly (giving 404 error)

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have installed CakePHP in my test server and it is working fine. When I moved the site to production server the site is not working. In  routes.php I have this code

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'occasions', 'action' => 'index'));
```

It is loading when there is no controller name and action name in the url. If I add the contoller name and action name in url the page giving an 404 error, i.e. `www.server.com/mycake` is working fine,
but `www.server.com/mycake/occasions/index` giving 404 error. The mod_rewrite is on in the server. And also the js and css are not loading with this code:

```
echo $html->css(array('style'));
echo $javascript->link(array('common_functions','jquery.min'));
```

Comment: Do you have debug level set to at least 1 in core.php?

Comment: Have you looked at the Apache logs to check if there are any useful error messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your rewriting isn't working properly.

/mycake will work fine because apache will redirect an base dir url to index.php, but url rewriting isn't working.

Maybe (just a guess) you need to include `RewriteBase /mycake` or similar for it to work properly.